# Get the _id of the created element instead of the whole data in mongodb

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I have a problem accessing the _id of the last created element inserted in to mongodbe.
is there any solution to just get the id, instead of getting all elements? especially if the data list is so long and nested so its really hard to pin the created element and gain access to his id
I am using mongoose driver on this one.

```js
let updateDeptArr = await Budget.findOneAndUpdate(
            // Dynamic 
            {
                '_id': `${propertyValues[0]}`, // user ID
                [`${keys[2]}._id`]: `${propertyValues[1]}`
            },
            {
                '$push': {
                    [`${keys[2]}.$.${keys[3]}`]: propertyValues[3]
                }
            }, { _id: true, new: true }
        ).then(function (data) {
            // we need to get and send The id of the last created element!!!
            console.log(data[keys[2]]);
            // let order = data[keys[1]].length - 1
            //  let id = data[keys[1]][`${order}`]._id
            //  res.json({ _id: id })
        })
    }
```

Comment: Hey there, I tried to help you yesterday, but I was busy. Did you try select?? see a sample below.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `select` after query.

In the upcoming listing, you have a mongoose schema being used to query MongoDB, and just two fields are selected, as you want.

```
Loc
.findById(req.params.locationid)
.select('name reviews')//select chained
.exec();
```

Try to chain select to your call. It will just give back the name and reviews.

Try this:

```
let updateDeptArr = await Budget.findOneAndUpdate(
            // Dynamic 
            {
                '_id': `${propertyValues[0]}`, // user ID
                [`${keys[2]}._id`]: `${propertyValues[1]}`
            },
            {
                '$push': {
                    [`${keys[2]}.$.${keys[3]}`]: propertyValues[3]
                }
            }, { _id: true, new: true }
        ).select("_id")// not sure if Mongoose will chain this way
        .then(function (data) {
            // we need to get and send The id of the last created element!!!
            console.log(data[keys[2]]);
            // let order = data[keys[1]].length - 1
            //  let id = data[keys[1]][`${order}`]._id
            //  res.json({ _id: id })
        })
    }
```

Comment: Mongoose will chain but the problem is it doesn't go to the nested id object. only the one that is outside, I am tying to find a solution how to get the nested object id

Comment: Try something like ```.select("nesteddoc_id") ```. If my memory serves me well. I have faced the same issue and that solved the problem.

Comment: correction: ```.select("nesteddoc._id")```